# how to combined data with same key

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

How to combine same key records in to one single key
how to add this array into single key value.

```
 {
            2014 =         {
                categoryName = Birthday;
                firstName = b1;
                flag = 1;
                id = 13;

            };
        },
            {
            2014 =         {
                categoryName = Birthday;
                firstName = b5;
                flag = 1;
                id = 17;
};
            }
        )


any one can please help me
```

Comment: Show the sample output for your sample input. What did you try so far?

Comment: add all portion (KEY -VALUE pair) add to array and use it.. no need to combine

Comment: I think your response somewhat wrong. Your all data wrap up into array under unique key of 2014.

Comment: @Wain i am trying to do combine year as key for different records with same year from my main array

Comment: So you want a dictionary with key year and value array of each item that currently has that year key? Easier if you show sample output...

Comment: @Wain Yes but all records get from array

Comment: i am trying with this code :: for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i ++) {
        
        for (int x = 0; x < [dataArray count]; x++) {
            
            if ([[[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"year"] isEqualToString:[[dataArray objectAtIndex:x]valueForKey:@"year"]]) {
                
                NSMutableDictionary *yearDict= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                [yearDict setObject:[dataArray objectAtIndex:x] forKey:[[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"year"]];
             [MainArray addObject:yearDict];
            }
        }
    }